# Passing data from Vue.js to PHP using Axios

Tags: javascript, php, html, vue.js, axios

I am trying to transmit some data from a GUI done in Vue.js to a PHP file using Axios. I tried both with GET and POST parameters but it does not work:

I type the data in this **index.php** *form*:

[image]

**index.php:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<BODY>
    <div id="container" class="container">
        <div>
            <label>First name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" v-model='newPerson.firstName'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Last name: </label><br/>
            <input type="text" v-model="newPerson.lastName">
        </div>
        <button v-on:click="sendIdentity()">Submit</button>       
    </div>    
    <script src="myjscode.js"></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**myjscode.js:**

When I press the button to submit the data, I see the right output in `console.log(response.data)`:

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: "#container",
    data: {
        newPerson: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendIdentity: function() {
            let personForm = vm.toFormData(vm.newPerson);
            axios.post('phpfile.php', personForm)
                .then( function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                });
        },
        toFormData: function(obj) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            for(let key in obj) {
                formData.append(key, obj[key]);
            }
            return formData;
        }
    }
});
```

**phpfile.php:**

On this file, I am rather performing an insertion into a MySQL table, however it never takes effect. I removed the MySQL code and let only what follows, where I notice I always get the message `Data not received` when I run this file:

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['firstName']) && isset($_POST['lastName'])){
   echo $_POST['firstName'];
   echo $_POST['lastName'];      
} else {  
   echo 'Data not received';
}
?>
```

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I noticed when I changed the ***myjscode.js*** above like ths:

```
axios.post('phpfile.php?todo=something', ...)
```

And then I change ***phpfile.php*** to

```
<?php

if( isset($_GET['todo']) ){
   echo $_GET['todo'];
} else {
   echo 'No todo';
}
?>
```

I am getting *No todo* always displayed on the PHP file. So sending data both via GET and POST do not work in this situation.

Comment: what's inside $_POST ? (PHP side)

Comment: I am hoping it is the data in the JS file which are updated by what I type in the input fields of the GUI

Comment: `axios.post('phpfile.php?todo=something', ...)`

Use a ? instead of / to append to the $_GET array.

Comment: What happens if you console.log vm.newPerson and personForm before the post? Are they both set?

Comment: They get both displayed accordingly @JacobW

Answer (score 7):

By default `axios` sends `requestBody` in `json` format and with `$_POST` you only can fetch `form-data`.

to fetch this `json` request in php, you need to fetch raw `requestBody` by typing: `file_get_contents('php://input')`

also send in `json` format, without - `vm.toFormData(vm.newPerson)`

I've created php file on my server to test.

js file content [here](https://pastebin.com/NGzkAWPQ)

php file content [here](https://pastebin.com/4qy7usMP)

Comment: can you try to send without `vm.toFormData(vm.newPerson)`?
just send JS Object

Comment: I did, I still can not see the data on the PHP file displayed

Comment: Which version of php do you have?

can you make sure that `php-json` is installed?

Comment: I have Php 7.2. Note that the data is displayed in the console (where I run **localhost/index,php**) but I just do not see it on **localhost/phpfile.php**

Comment: also print `$requestBody` after line:
`$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: Strange... Is the file exact same as I've posted? or something (another php file) is included/required above?

Comment: Yes, I posted the exact 3 files I am using.

Answer (score 4):

Your best option might be to set the content-type header so PHP knows what data type to expect.

```
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/form-data' },
  data: personForm,
  url: 'phpfile.php',
};
axios(options);
```

Edit:

Create a shared instance of axios for the best results and ease of use.

```
## Filename /utils/axios.js
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/ or file.php',
    timeout: 1000,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'},
    transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
        // Do whatever you want to transform the data
        let formData = new FormData();
        for(let key in data) {
            formData.append(key, obj[key]);
        }
        return formData;
    }],
});

export default instance;
```

Then in your component file you'd require this instance of `/utils/axios.js` above like `const axios = require('./utils/axios')` and now you've got a shared instance with the same config to use throughout. On top of that the above config will use transformRequest to turn your json object into formdata every time so you don't have to do it at the component level.
Below in your components code you'd do:

```
axios
    .post(jsonObjectofData)
    .then()
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Edit: Webpackless method

```
let vm = new Vue({
    el: "#container",
    data: {
        newPerson: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        sendIdentity: function() {
            let personForm = vm.toFormData(vm.newPerson);
            const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'content-type': 'application/form-data' },
                data: personForm,
                url: 'phpfile.php',
            };
            axios(options)
                .then( function(response) {
                    console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err);
        },
        toFormData: function(obj) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            for(let key in obj) {
                formData.append(key, obj[key]);
            }
            return formData;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there an error being output or a response in the then piece of axios? You might have bad configuration set up rather than bad code.

How is your local PHP server being run, command line or another tool? I've used the above config without issue in javascript and react for axios.

Comment: I use Axios and Vue.js from the CDN because I am just testing short examples for the moment (beginner in these 2 techs)

Comment: Ohh you're not using a transpiler like webpack?

Comment: Check the updated method I posted above and see if that works for you.

Comment: No, I'm wondering if you're actually hitting the php file at all with your configuration. Can you try to hit the PHP file using a tool like postman?

Is there anything returned in the response or the network panel of chrome?

Comment: So when your using AJAX it is doing a post request. When you just open the file it's a get request.

Are you with me there?